# spark-streaming: how to output streaming data to cassandra

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am reading kafka streaming messages using spark-streaming.
Now I want to set Cassandra as my output.
I have created a table in cassandra "test_table" with columns "key:text primary key" and "value:text"
I have mapped the data successfully into `JavaDStream<Tuple2<String,String>> data` like this:

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext("local[4]", "SparkStream",conf);
JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, new Duration(3000));

JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> messages = KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, args[0], args[1], topicMap );
JavaDStream<Tuple2<String,String>> data = messages.map(new Function< Tuple2<String,String>, Tuple2<String,String> >() 
{
    public Tuple2<String,String> call(Tuple2<String, String> message)
    {
        return new Tuple2<String,String>( message._1(), message._2() );
    }
}
);
```

Then I have created a List:

```
List<TestTable> list = new ArrayList<TestTable>();
```

where TestTable is my custom class having the same structure as my Cassandra table, with members "key" and "value":

```
class TestTable
{
    String key;
    String val;

    public TestTable() {}

    public TestTable(String k, String v)
    {
        key=k;
        val=v;
    }

    public String getKey(){
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String k){
        key=k;
    }

    public String getVal(){
        return val;
    }

    public void setVal(String v){
        val=v;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Key:"+key+",Val:"+val;
    }
}
```

Please suggest a way how to I add the data from `JavaDStream<Tuple2<String,String>> data` into the `List<TestTable> list`.
I am doing this so that I can subsequently use

```
JavaRDD<TestTable> rdd = sc.parallelize(list); 
javaFunctions(rdd, TestTable.class).saveToCassandra("testkeyspace", "test_table");
```

to save the RDD data into Cassandra.

I had tried coding this way:

```
messages.foreachRDD(new Function<Tuple2<String,String>, String>()
                        {
                            public List<TestTable> call(Tuple2<String,String> message)
                            {
                                String k = message._1();
                                String v = message._2();
                                TestTable tbl = new TestTable(k,v);
                                list.put(tbl);
                            }
                        }
                    );
```

but seems some type mis-match happenning.
Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that the intention of this program is to save the streaming data from kafka into Cassandra, it's not necessary to dump the `JavaDStream<Tuple2<String,String>>` data into a `List<TestTable>` list.

The Spark-Cassandra connector by DataStax supports this functionality directly through the [Spark Streaming extensions](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/7_java_api.md#extensions-for-spark-streaming).

It should be sufficient to use such extensions on the `JavaDStream`:

```
javaFunctions(data).writerBuilder("testkeyspace", "test_table", mapToRow(TestTable.class)).saveToCassandra();
```

instead of draining data on an intermediary list.

Comment: @maasg- Thank u, now i am able to create a connection. but now the data is not getting inserted into the cassandra table. and the logs show its getting connected and the next second getting disconnected. the full code and the logs and dependencies are at "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27386223/spark-data-not-getting-written-into-cassandra-zero-rows-inserted"